# Get origin url of 301/302 Forward in PHP/Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, redirect, header, domain-forwarding

I have a small question: from different domains, I'm forwarding via 301/302 to one distinct target domain.

On the target Server I have a running apache.

I need to know the origin Domain - so from which "source"-domain was the user forwarded to the target domain?!

Is this possible to achieve in PHP / Javascript?

Thanks in advance for your help and greetings from Germany

Comment: You could try the Referer header in the request, but it's not guaranteed

Comment: If you are in control of the redirects, then append a query string parameter maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a URL Parameter in the redirection, e.g. `[..].de/?h=origindomain`.

Then you are able to readout the parameter with `$_GET["h"]`.